# Problem with org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Hostip, running Qreator on Xubuntu-14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, python

I installed [Qreator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/qreator/) using `apt-get` on Xubuntu-14.04:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qreator
```

But the application fails to start!

When I try to run it via Terminal, the following error messages are printed and the program aborts:

```
$ qreator

** (qreator:3859): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-Gh2FPHrMr2: Connection refused
No handlers could be found for logger "qreator_lib"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/qreator", line 47, in <module>
    qreator.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator/__init__.py", line 63, in main
    window = QreatorWindow.QreatorWindow()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator_lib/Window.py", line 48, in __new__
    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator/QreatorWindow.py", line 79, in finish_initializing
    self.init_qr_types()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator/QreatorWindow.py", line 135, in init_qr_types
    self.qr_types = [d(self.update_qr_code) for d in QRCodeType.dataformats]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator/qrcodes/QRCodeType.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.create_widget()  # pylint: disable=E1101
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator/qrcodes/QRCodeLocation.py", line 29, in create_widget
    self.widget = QRCodeLocationGtk(self.qr_code_update_func)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator/qrcodes/QRCodeLocationGtk.py", line 49, in __init__
    latitude, longitude = get_current_location()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qreator/qrcodes/QRCodeLocationGtk.py", line 109, in get_current_location
    '/org/freedesktop/Geoclue/Providers/Hostip')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Hostip was not provided by any .service files
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one dependency is missing (to provide `org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.Hostip`).

Try to install the following [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/geoclue-hostip):

```
sudo apt-get install geoclue-hostip
```

Comment: But I have Qreator working without that package...

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked and it's working now! If this package is required, then why it's not in the dependencies?!

Comment: Time to file a bug for this package ;)